# How can I limit unicode characters from database?

Tags: mysql, unicode

I have my native language store in mysql database look like this

> កីឡាករ​រក​ចំណូល​បាន​ខ្ពស់​​បំផុត​មួយ​នៅ​លើ​លោក ដោយ​រក​បាន​ជិត​១​លាន​ផោន

but I want to limit it only 100 characters to show and if more than 100 show ...

I use this code

> echo substr($row[1],0,100).((strlen($row[1])>100)? '...' : '');

It works well if the data in database is English characters,but for my native 
language character it doesn't work. In database i set

> Type = text, Collation = utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
        CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(khmer) > 100 THEN khmer
            ELSE CONCAT(LEFT(khmer, 98), '...')
            END
    FROM ...
```

Note the use of `CHAR_LENGTH` instead of `LENGTH`.